# Get particular page from Word document using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml

I want to convert each page of document into separate word document. So i need to get every page of document. I am not able to differentiate pages in open xml format.
So please move me to right direction.

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open("test.docx", true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
}
```

Comment: you do this with code. Once youve given it a go and have some code to show us and a specific 'code related' problem then we can help you

Comment: The OOXML dont have a page concept. Who draw the page breaks is the software that are consuming this xml (Word for exemple)... Because, if you want a "Print View" this make sense, but, if you want a "Web View", page breaks dont make sense

Comment: @Bruno.cf: I know that hence i asked this question.

Comment: Short answer: Not possible at the OOXML data level alone.  [See here for a detailed explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139811/290085)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.lastrenderedpagebreak.aspx), The client uses `LastRenderedPageBreak` toidentify pages when its last saved. and the xml for it is:

```
<w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
```

I think you can use this to check and break pages unless the document you are working with is auto generated and haven't got any `lastRenderedPageBreak`s.

Also this approach will only work for documents with single column layouts. But with documents with multi column layouts [looks like there are issues.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/3d0a3027-3062-4ecf-9e74-50cea3ae9a60)