# How can I find the Page Count of a Word Document with Python?

Tags: python, django, ms-word, docx

I have tried the approach of finding the page count in the `docProps/app.xml` file but this isn't very robust as the values can be easily manipulated. As I require this functionality for a website, I can't use `win32com.client` because it only works on Windows with Word installed.

Is there a reliable way of finding the page count using Python?

Comment: You could read the whole document with python-docx to a string and then count the words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access OpenXML content by page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992870/how-to-access-openxml-content-by-page-number)

Comment: Page count is a property dependent upon the pagination algorithm of the processing software.  Simulating Word's (or any other software's) pagination is complex, so your question is simple, but its answer is not.   See  [How to access OpenXML content by page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992870/how-to-access-openxml-content-by-page-number)