# Python get line position (top, left, bottom, right) from DOCX to HTML

Tags: python, html, xml, openxml, docx

I have a document like this [document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39w40.png), I want to convert the DOCX file into HTML file by using Python package **docx**:
`docx.convert_to_html(input)`.

I am wondering is there any method or Python package that I can extract the position from each line?
The position represents the boundary of each line in relative location in a page.

I want my ultimate HTML result looks like this:

```
<line b="38" id="line_0" l="616" r="795" style="white-space:nowrap; position:absolute; left:616px;top:14px; font-size:19.0px; " t="14">DOC
# 2019-0046594<br></line>
```

Regardless of the format, I need the four position values of "l, r, b, t".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract positional line rendering information from a DOCX file because DOCX files do not represent such information explicitly.  Word wrapping and line rendering algorithms are implementation-dependent.

The same is true of DOCX page numbering in general: See [How to access OpenXML content by page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39992870/290085)